# Which one is correct and idiomatic

Tags: prepositions

> I bought this with cash
>  
>   I bought this by cash

The first one sounds idiomatic. But second one doesn't sound bad though

Answer (score 2):

I bought this with cash.  Never heard anyone say "by cash" that I can recall.  It is understandable, I would know what you meant, but it would sound awkward to me.

Answer (score 1):

To my ear, "with cash" is idiomatic. "By cash" is possible, but a bit odd. I would probably use it only contrastively, as in "I bought this one by card, but this one by cash". Even in that  case, I would probably still say "with cash".

**Edit**: Ronald Sole points out that "for cash" is also quite comon.

Comment: _using_ works, too: _I bought this using cash_. I still like the “with” version the best.

Comment: I have heard: *I bought it for cash* although *to sell for cash* is far more common.